# Resolving XML entities without using lxml's "resolve_entities" option

Tags: python, xml, sonarqube, lxml

I have an XML file which has some entities that need to be resolved,
but I get the Sonar error https://rules.sonarsource.com/python/RSPEC-2755 when setting `resolve_entities=True` in `lxml.etree.XMLParser`.

Comment: Please also share the xml.

Comment: There is an attack type that is based on expanding XML entities in specially crafted, malicious XML documents that use recursive entities (XXE, aka XML bomb). `lxml` is vulnerable to this type of attack. You can't have it both ways - either you are expanding entities, then you theoretically vulnerable, or you don't, then the parsed XML document theoretically does not look like you want it to. You can't expand entities and not be vulnerable at the same time. If you're sure that the XML documents you parse are from a trustworthy source, ignore the message.